# Wifi Not Working Elementary Os Loki 0.4.1

Tags: release-loki, networking

I installed Elementary OS 0.4 about 2-3 months ago. Currently I am dual-booting it with Ubuntu 16.10, Lubuntu 16.04, and Deepin 15.4. My wifi (I haven't checked ethernet) does not work on any of them! I can connect to a network but after loading a web page, it says something along the lines of, "No Internet Connection).

So Elementary OS was the only system where the wifi worked for a long time. Now, however, ever since the update from 0.4 to 0.4.1 it's not working on eOS either!

Since Elementary OS is my main OS I would like to have it fixed first. By the way, running `lshw -c network` returns this:

```
    *-network DISABLED      
       description: Wireless interface
       product: BCM4321 802.11a/b/g/n
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wls4
       version: 03
       serial: 00:21:e9:de:6b:0e
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.271 (r587334) latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
       resources: irq:16 memory:90500000-90503fff memory:90000000-900fffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 88E8058 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Marvell Technology Group Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: ens5
       version: 13
       serial: 00:22:41:2d:43:14
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm vpd msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=sky2 driverversion=1.30 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:27 memory:90400000-90403fff ioport:5000(size=256) memory:90420000-9043ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: enp0s26f7u2
       serial: a6:63:9d:eb:e5:2d
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.214 link=yes multicast=yes
```

The wifi is disable right now because I'm connected via tethering.

PS: I am using my Android tablet for tethering in order to connect to the Internet.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a working Internet connection via Ethernet, run this:

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source

Reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Had a problem with Wifi stopped discovering networks all of a sudden.

```
Card-2: Intel Wireless 7265 driver: iwlwifi bus-ID: 02:00.0
```

rfkill list all

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: dell-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

dmesg |grep wifi

```
[    5.392851] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-26.ucode failed with error -2
[    5.392864] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-25.ucode failed with error -2
[    5.393317] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-24.ucode failed with error -2
[    5.393650] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-23.ucode failed with error -2
[    5.433524] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 22.391740.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    5.767168] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7265, REV=0x210
[    5.769654] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    5.770166] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    5.878407] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
[   18.011141] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: RF_KILL bit toggled to disable radio.
[   33.845813] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: RF_KILL bit toggled to enable radio.
[  224.671159] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: RF_KILL bit toggled to disable radio.
[  226.270719] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: RF_KILL bit toggled to enable radio.
[  226.282792] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[  226.283240] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[  226.349644] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[  226.350193] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
```

No solution posted in Internet helped.
Then a miracle happened.

Went to `System Settings`,`Network`, `Wifi` and noticed although it was turned `ON`, the comment below said it is turned `OFF`.

So I switched it `OFF` there, and switched it `ON` again. And is started working as before.